# How to resize an image with OpenCV2.0 and Python2.6

Tags: python, image, image-processing, resize, opencv

I want to use OpenCV2.0 and Python2.6 to show resized images. I used and adopted [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) example but unfortunately, this code is for OpenCV2.1 and does not seem to be working on 2.0. Here my code:

```
import os, glob
import cv

ulpath = "exampleshq/"

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(ulpath, "*.jpg") ):
    im = cv.LoadImage(infile)
    thumbnail = cv.CreateMat(im.rows/10, im.cols/10, cv.CV_8UC3)
    cv.Resize(im, thumbnail)
    cv.NamedWindow(infile)
    cv.ShowImage(infile, thumbnail)
    cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyWindow(name)
```

Since I cannot use

```
cv.LoadImageM
```

I used

```
cv.LoadImage
```

instead, which was no problem in other applications. Nevertheless, cv.iplimage has no attribute rows, cols or size. Can anyone give me a hint, how to solve this problem?

Comment: If any of answers was correct, please mark it as it will help others.

Answer (score 436):

If you wish to use CV2, you need to use the `resize` function.

For example, this will resize both axes by half:

```
small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
```

and this will resize the image to have 100 cols (width) and 50 rows (height):

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 50))
```

Another option is to use `scipy` module, by using:

```
small = scipy.misc.imresize(image, 0.5)
```

There are obviously more options you can read in the documentation of those functions ([cv2.resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize), [scipy.misc.imresize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)).

---

**Update:**
According to the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html):

> `imresize` is **deprecated** in SciPy 1.0.0, and
>   will be removed in 1.2.0. 
> Use [`skimage.transform.resize`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) instead.

Note that if you're looking to **resize by a factor**, you may actually want [`skimage.transform.rescale`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale).

Comment: does not  the resize() function make the picture loosing information about itself ?

Comment: Yes, you can't reduce the size of the image without losing information.

Comment: The opencv (0.05ms per image) implementation seems to be much faster than the scipy (0.33ms image) implementation. I resized 210x160x1 to 84x84x1 images with bilinear interpolation.

Comment: @gizzmole Interesting insight. I did not test the efficiency of the implementations, nor compared the results - so the end result may also differ slightly. Did you test to see the resized images match bitwise?

Comment: Thaks for pointing out that resize function take (W * H) whereas cv2 print as (H  * W)

Comment: how to resize by dpi?

Comment: @yozawiratama I don't think I understand your question, or why it is related to the original question - dpi is defined by the size of the image as it is displayed (or printed) in the real world, and by the number of information dots (usually pixels) it has.

Comment: does `cv2.resize` automatically uses padding? what is the size of the window that is created using desired output as `(100, 50)`?

Comment: In reply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195453/how-to-resize-an-image-with-opencv2-0-and-python2-6#comment47735184_18767569 , in many cases, information would be lost unless the image is something like a trivial blank image or two squares or some SVG rendering.

Comment: @emem i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Answer (score 84):

### Example doubling the image size

There are two ways to resize an image. The new size can be specified:

1. Manually;

   `height, width = src.shape[:2]`

   `dst = cv2.resize(src, (2*width, 2*height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`
2. By a scaling factor.

   `dst = cv2.resize(src, None, fx = 2, fy = 2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`,
   where **fx** is the scaling factor along the horizontal axis and **fy** along the vertical axis.

To shrink an image, it will generally look best with INTER_AREA interpolation, whereas to enlarge an image, it will generally look best with INTER_CUBIC (slow) or INTER_LINEAR (faster but still looks OK).

### Example shrink image to fit a max height/width (keeping aspect ratio)

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('YOUR_PATH_TO_IMG')

height, width = img.shape[:2]
max_height = 300
max_width = 300

# only shrink if img is bigger than required
if max_height < height or max_width < width:
    # get scaling factor
    scaling_factor = max_height / float(height)
    if max_width/float(width) < scaling_factor:
        scaling_factor = max_width / float(width)
    # resize image
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

cv2.imshow("Shrinked image", img)
key = cv2.waitKey()
```

### Using your code with cv2

```
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread(path)

height, width = im.shape[:2]

thumbnail = cv.resize(im, (round(width / 10), round(height / 10)), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

cv.imshow('exampleshq', thumbnail)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: your solution using the scaling factors returns an error on cv2.resize() saying 'src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar.' please advise?

Comment: did you do: `src = cv2.imread('YOUR_PATH_TO_IMG')` and edited the 'YOUR_PATH_TO_IMG' to the path of your own image?

Comment: does `cv2.resize` automatically uses padding? what is the size of the window that is created using desired output size as `(width/10, height/10)`?

Comment: @makaros you get an image that is 10x smaller both in width and height

Comment: @JoãoCartucho yes I understand this. But when nearest_neighbors is used then a window should applied behind the scenes. This is what I am asking..

Comment: what nearest_neighbors?

Answer (score 9):

You could use the GetSize function to get those information, 
    cv.GetSize(im) 
would return a tuple with the width and height of the image. 
You can also use im.depth and img.nChan to get some more information.

And to resize an image, I would use a slightly different process, with another image instead of a matrix. It is better to try to work with the same type of data:

```
size = cv.GetSize(im)
thumbnail = cv.CreateImage( ( size[0] / 10, size[1] / 10), im.depth, im.nChannels)
cv.Resize(im, thumbnail)
```

Hope this helps ;)

Julien

Answer (score 8):

Here's a function to upscale or downscale an image by desired width or height while maintaining aspect ratio

```
# Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # Return original image if no need to resize
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # We are resizing height if width is none
    if width is None:
        # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    # We are resizing width if height is none
    else:
        # Calculate the ratio of the width and construct the dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # Return the resized image
    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
```

Usage

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
cv2.imshow('width_100', maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(image, width=100))
cv2.imshow('width_300', maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(image, width=300))
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

Using this example image

[image]

Simply downscale to `width=100` (left) or upscale to `width=300` (right)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
def rescale_by_height(image, target_height, method=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4):
    """Rescale `image` to `target_height` (preserving aspect ratio)."""
    w = int(round(target_height * image.shape[1] / image.shape[0]))
    return cv2.resize(image, (w, target_height), interpolation=method)

def rescale_by_width(image, target_width, method=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4):
    """Rescale `image` to `target_width` (preserving aspect ratio)."""
    h = int(round(target_width * image.shape[0] / image.shape[1]))
    return cv2.resize(image, (target_width, h), interpolation=method)
```

Comment: does `cv2.resize` automatically uses padding? what is the size of the window that is created using `(w, target_height)` arguments?