# WIDTH and HEIGHT parameters in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

l'm a little bit confused on width and height parameter :

Is the height which is the first parameter or the second ?

`HEIGHT,WIDTH= img.shape[0:2]`   or `WIDTH,HEIGHt= img.shape[0:2]`

and in resize function `height=32 and width=100` or the inverse ?

```
image=cv2.resize(img, (32, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Comment: it's height first, this follows common array semantics where it's Row length followed by Column length

Comment: even for the function resize ?

Comment: What you have written is correct, the `size` passed takes the param order height, width which is what you've written

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html  here in the function resize width first

Comment: l think for the function resize the parameters are (width,height)

Comment: That seems a little odd to me, when you look at the `shape` of an array the first value is the number of rows so it's height then width, and most size ops expect this order so I'm a bit surprised but in this case this maybe be reverse order, you may also find this post useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195453/how-to-resize-an-image-with-opencv2-0-and-python2-6

Comment: @EdChum, thanks in the link you just gave : it's resize(width,height)  but height,width=image.shape

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little surprised to be honest, not sure why, all other methods to my knowledge use the same axes order

Comment: try an example to confirm that

Comment: If it's a _size_ is _width and height_, if it's a _shape_ it's _rows and cols_. That's pretty standard convention. Just remember that _width == cols_ and _height == rows_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With .shape it's `HEIGHT, WIDTH = img.shape[0:2]`. The reason for this, is it's a numpy matrix, where the first value means number of rows, and the second is number of columns.

When you resize it's `img = cv2.resize(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can verify by yourself... 
When you do something like:

```
Mat occludedSquare= imread("p4.jpg");
```

then you find a matrix like:

[image]

but the p4 image is actually:
width: 339 
high: 372

so OpenCV is associating ***rows  →  high*** and ***cols  → width***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common (for me) to be confused.
So, just copy the snippet from now on:

```py
img = cv2.imread('./my_img.png')

resized_img = cv2.resize(img, 
                         (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]) 
                        )
# HEIGHT, WIDTH = img.shape[0:2]
# resized_img   = cv2.resize(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
```

---

### 1

[image]
[constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/db/d4e/classcv_1_1Point__.html#a8db927bb4ec0aa348367566cb6219c0f)

[image]

### 2

[image]
[constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d50/classcv_1_1Size__.html#a45c97e9a4930d73fde11c2acc5f371ac) of the `Size` class

[image]

### 3

[image]

construct function of the `Mat` class

1. `Mat(int rows,      int cols , int type)`
2. `Mat(Size(int cols, int rows), int type)`

- **Mat**  use (row,col)
- **Point** and **Size** use `(x,y)`, or notate as `(width,height)`

In other words, these access the same point:

- `mat.at<type>(y,x)`(cpp)
  or   `your_img_ndarray[y][x]`(python)
- `mat.at<type>(cv::Point(x,y))` (cpp)

---

### The opencv [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) is mainly for C++ code:

[image]

- dsize:    size of output image
  if it equals zero (None in Python), it is computed as:

`dsize = Size(round(fx*src.cols), round(fy*src.rows))`

**1. explicitly specify dsize=dst.size()** :
fx and fy will be computed from that.

```
resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, interpolation);
```

- fx:   scale factor along the horizontal axis; when it equals 0, it is computed as
  `(double)dsize.width/src.cols`

**2. specify fx and fy ,  let the function compute the destination image size.**

```cpp
resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation);
```