# What is the name of this image similarity/ distance based metric?

Tags: image, numpy, distance

I used the following code to calculate the similarity between images 1 and 2 (i1 and i2). 1=exactly similar while 0=very different. I'd like to know what method this algorithm is using (i.e. Euclidian distance or..?) Thank you.

```
import math
i1=all_images_saved[0][1]
i2=all_images_saved[0][2]
i1_norm = i1/np.sqrt(np.sum(i1**2))
i2_norm = i2/np.sqrt(np.sum(i2**2))
np.sum(i1_norm*i2_norm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). You can check it gives the same results as:

```
from scipy import spatial 
cosine_distance = spatial.distance.cosine(i1.flatten(), i2.flatten()) 
cosine_similarity = 1 - cosine_distance
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a distance, otherwise 0 would mean identical. This looks like the dot product of 2 normalized vectors in which case I would say about the original vectors that they are (with the range of values from -1 to 1 being in between the thresholds describe below):

- `1` = co-directional
- `0` = orthogonal
- `-1` = opposite direction

And given the [geometric definition of the dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition), if you have the dot product and the magnitude of your vectors you can derive the angle between the 2:

```
a . b = ||a|| ||b|| cos θ
```

Or have I completely missed something here?

Comment: Someone recommended this metric to tell how similar two images are. Is it not doing that?

Comment: Mathematically it gives similarity of images seen as matrices. But if you mean how humans perceive images it might not be suitable (eg take 1 image, crop 2 smaller images from it with a small offset between the 2: the images will look similar to a human, but mathematically all pixels are off thus the math might say they are dissimilar. Normalization might help (eg centering/reshape for specific images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914035/how-to-centralize-and-resize-digits-using-opencv) but usually with images you get better results using neural nets thx to flexibility of convolution